# Yii is not letting me use aliases in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii2

The following code returns an error:

```
       $orders = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT
                                            Orders.CustomerName AS BillingName
                                              FROM `Orders`
                                              WHERE `CustomerId` = :student_id ORDER BY Orders.`EntryDate` DESC")->bindValues([":student_id" => $student_id])->queryAll();
    $orders_result = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $total_books_price = 0;
        $orders_result[$i] = [
            "BillingName" => $order["CustomerName"],

        ];
```

But if I replace the `SELECT COLUMN AS ALIAS` with `SELECT *`, it works fine.

Comment: Please update your question. `$order["CustomerName"]` cannot work if you have `AS BillingName`.